# how to build an object and store it as hstore type on postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, hashmap, pg

I am trying to build an object on nodejs and then store it to a postgres database as hstore datatype. 
For example in java you would do something like:

```
private mapObject = new Map<string, string>();
mapObject(firstString) = secondString;
```

and then you push that to database.

How would I create such an object in nodejs, not sure if necessary need a javascript hashmap object or how can I do it?
I am using nodejs and pg library to connect to postgres database

Answer (score 1):

He text representation of an hstore, used for input and output, includes zero or more key => value pairs separated by commas. Some examples:

```
k => v
foo => bar, baz => whatever
"1-a" => "anything at all"
```

The next thing to do is to install Sequelize and some other dependencies:

```
npm install --save sequelize pg pg-hstore
```

to use:

```
field_name: {
        type: Sequelize.HSTORE()
      },
```

Current Functionality

```
User.findOne({
  where: {
    hstore_field: {
      fieldOne: 'some_value',
    },
  },
});
```

would produce

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE hstore_field = '"fieldOne" => "some_value"'
New functionality
User.findOne({
  where: {
    hstore_field: {
      $contains: {
        fieldOne: 'some_value',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

would produce

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE hstore_field -> 'fieldOne' = 'some_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i will answer using [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) (promise-based ORM for Node.js v4 and up).

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
User.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  // Table created using object format
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Hancock'
  });
});

//optional to use anything you want
```

Thats code from `sequelizejs` documentation.